# Count input fields after adding and removing it with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

eOk i add and remove input fields with this code, but maximum nubmer of input fields its not proper counted, problem is in this line  $('.remove_field').click( function(e) . when i call this line href tagets all clasess with same name so x-- is decrement more times than one, for example if i have 4 inputs x will be counted x-4. How to solve this problem in easy way.

```
$('document').ready(function()
        {
           var max = 5;
           var x = 1;

            $('#add').click(function(e)
            {  
                if(x < max)
                {
                    $('#inp').append('<div><input class = "new_input" type=text name="name[]" placeholder="Unesite podatak"/><a class="remove_field "href="#"> X</a><div><br/>');
                    x++;
            }

            $('.remove_field').click( function(e)
            {   
                e.preventDefault();
                $(this).parent('div').remove();
             x--;

            })

            });
        });
```

i tried somethig like this

```
 $(#inp).on('click','.remove_field',function(e){})
```

but it doesnt work for me??? Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

You are using a div tag instead of and end div tag in the following statement:

```
$('#inp').append('<div><input class = "new_input" type=text name="name[]" placeholder="Unesite podatak"/><a class="remove_field "href="#"> X</a><div><br/>');
```

**Should be:**

```
$('#inp').append('<div><input class = "new_input" type=text name="name[]" placeholder="Unesite podatak"/><a class="remove_field "href="#"> X</a></div><br/>');
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't test it, but just from looking at it, i can see you are missing  `}`  on your `if (x < max)` statement (closing brackets after `x++;`)

Answer (score 0):

What's happening is that you are adding an additional event handler to all existing inputs every time #add is clicked on. Thus, you can do a query on the class remove_field, but only ask for the last one.

```
$('.remove_field').last()
```

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/timctran/j2oftq6v/

```
<div id="add">Click to Add an Input</div>
<div id="inp"></div>

<script>
var max = 5;
var x = 0;

$('#add').click(function() { 
    if (x<5) {
        $('#inp').append(' \
            <div> \
                <input class="new_input" type=text name="name"/> \
                <a class="remove_field" href="#"> X </a> \
            </div> \
        ');
        x++;
        $('.remove_field').last().click( function(e) {
            $(this).parent('div').remove();
            x--;
        });
    }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<script>
$('document').ready(function()
        {
           var max = 5;
           var x = 1;

            $('#add').click(function(e)
            {  
                if(x < max)
                {
                    $('#inp').append('<div><input class = "new_input" type=text name="name[]" placeholder="Unesite podatak"/><a class="remove_field "href="#"> X</a><div><br/>');
                    x++;
            }
            });
            $('.remove_field').click( function(e)
            {   
                e.preventDefault();
                $(this).parent('div').remove();
             x--;

            });

            $('body').on('click','.remove_field',function(e){

                $('div#inp')[0].childNodes[max-1].remove();
max = max-1;
});
        });
</script>

<button class="remove_field">remove</button>
<button id="add">add</button>
<div id="inp">
</div>
```

but here i am removing the last field on each click of remove.